# Android Studio don't recognize implementetion

Tags: android, xml, implementation

I want to add depencies of CordinatorLayout, when i add Its like Android Studio don't recognize the dependencies, and I dont't know if is question of a version and i have to  actualize the app.`implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"`

Thank for your support

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="toDoListToolBarIconAdapter">enter code here
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: You don't need dependency for that

Comment: the error means that i have to add dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should try to avoid using **"** in your implementation because this was done prior to the point when **compile** was used.

Change  `implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"` to `implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'`.

It should solve your problem!

Also the Correct Process of using Coordinator Layout in your xml is:

```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

If it doesn't, then mention your whole Build.gradle file in your question by updating.

Cheers,
therbtcdr